# Last record value is displayed, not all values are looped

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, rally

In the code below, in _copyChild and innerModelRetrieved functions print on console 4 features one by one, but in next function onInnerModelRetrieved 4 times last feature value is printed, I am not able to figure it why its happening like that. please help me with this.

```
        Ext.define('CustomApp', {               
            extend: 'Rally.app.App',
            componentCls: 'app',
            _newObj : {},
            childrens: [],
            _type : null,
            launch: function() {
                Ext.create('Rally.ui.dialog.ChooserDialog', {
                    width: 450,
                    autoScroll: true,
                    height: 525,
                    title: 'Select to Copy',
                    pageSize: 100,
                    closable: false,
                    selectionButtonText: 'Copy',                  
                    artifactTypes: ['PortfolioItem/Feature','PortfolioItem/MMF','PortfolioItem/Epic', 'PortfolioItem/Program'],
                    autoShow: true,
                    storeConfig:{
                        fetch: ['Name','PortfolioItemTypeName']
                    },
                    listeners: {
                        artifactChosen: function(selectedRecord) {
                            childrens = [];
                            this._type = selectedRecord.get('PortfolioItemTypeName');
                            this._newObj = selectedRecord;
                            this.onqModelRetrieved();
                            var self = this;
                            Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
                                model: 'PortfolioItem/' + selectedRecord.get('PortfolioItemTypeName'),
                                fetch: ['Name', 'FormattedID', 'Children'],
                                pageSize: 1,
                                autoLoad: true,
                                listeners: {
                                    load: function(store, records) {
                                        final_features = [];
                                        Ext.Array.each(records, function(child){
                                            var item = selectedRecord;
                                            childrens = item.getCollection('Children');
                                            childrens.load({
                                                fetch: ['FormattedID'],
                                                callback: function(records, operation, success){
                                                    Ext.Array.each(records, function(portfolioitem){
                                                        if (portfolioitem.get('PortfolioItemTypeName') == "Feature") {
                                                            self._childObj = portfolioitem;
                                                            self._copyChild();
                                                        }   
                                                    }, self);   
                                                },
                                                scope: this 
                                            });     
                                        }, self);
                                    }   
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        scope: this
                    },
                }); 
            },
            // Inner Copy functions
            _copyChild: function() {
                console.log("child value here", that._childObj);
                this.innerModelRetrieved();
            },
            innerModelRetrieved: function() {
                var that = this
                console.log("next child value here", that._childObj);
                that._type = 'PortfolioItem/' + that._childObj.get('PortfolioItemTypeName');
                Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
                    type: that._type,
                    success: that.onInnerModelRetrieved,
                    scope: that
                });     
            },                      
            onInnerModelRetrieved: function(model) {
                console.log("next child value here", this._childObj);
                this.model = model;
                this.genericInnerCopy(model);
            },
```

Comment: You should clean up your code and post an example that can be properly formatted. As it currently exists, it's a garbled mess.

Comment: @existdissolve - sorry..I will edit and post it again.

Comment: @existdissolve - I think now code is more readable. Can you make sense out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make this work you need to create a block scope and a local variable that is set to the current `childObj`, otherwise `onInnerModelRetrieved` gets only the last value of childObj since it waits for the iterations over results to complete before it kicks in.

The function

`(function(){...})();`

immediately invoked creates that block scope and

`var child = that._childObj`

captures individual objects at each iteration.

Finally, the child is passed via

`success: function(model)`

which invokes `onInnerModelRetrieved` with two parameters, `model` and `child`

```
innerModelRetrieved: function() {
    var that = this;
    (function(){
         var child = that._childObj;
         console.log("in innerModelRetrieved, that._childObj.data.FormattedID:", that._childObj.data.FormattedID);
          that._type = 'PortfolioItem/' + that._childObj.get('PortfolioItemTypeName');
          Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
          type: that._type,
          success: function(model){
               that.onInnerModelRetrieved(model, child );
          },
          scope: that
          });
       })();
},                      
onInnerModelRetrieved: function(model, _childObj ) {
       console.log("in onInnerModelRetrieved, that._childObj.data.FormattedID:", _childObj.data.FormattedID);
       this.model = model;                
}
```

Here is the screenshot before the changes:

[image]

And here is the screenshot after changes:

[image]

Comment: u r just awesome. I also tried success as function, but still it was not working. Thanks a ton. I was waiting for this. You made my day.