# Want to set Parent of portfolioitem/feature

Tags: javascript, extjs, rally

I am trying to set Parent for portfolioitem/feature object, using set() method and then commit(). But Parent attribute is not set. ANy suggestions on this. Thanks in advance

```
genericInnerCopy: function(_childObj) {
   that = _childObj;
   console.log("parent MMF object", _newParent);
   var record = Ext.create(this.model, {
     Name: that.get('Name'),
     //Parent: _newParent,
   });
   record.save({
     callback: function(result, operation) {
     if(operation.wasSuccessful()) {
       result.set('Parent', _newParent);
       result.commit();
     }
     else{
       console.log("error");
     }
     }
   });
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what `_newParent` contains. It should be a `_ref` of the object, not the whole object or anything else:

```
/portfolioitem/initiative/1234567
```

See a full example of creating a feature and setting its initiative parent in [this github repo.](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/create-feature-set-parent)
In your code you may not be able to do `_newParent.get('_ref')` and instead `_newParent.data._ref`depending on how you arrived at the object.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem I was trying to copy whole object, it worked. But now this function I am calling for each feature object, and only last feature object parent is getting set.  See this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26097883/not-able-to-update-parent-for-all-portfolioitem-feature-which-i-copied-for-parti]. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're welcome. To me it sounds similar to closure in the loop problem posted here, when only the last record in the results was accessible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967655/last-record-value-is-displayed-not-all-values-are-looped

Comment: this is the error I am getting `Concurrency conflict: [Object has been modified since being read for update in this context] - ConcurrencyConflictException : Modified since read on update : Object Class : com.f4tech.slm.domain.PortfolioItem : ObjectID : 23365091021"length: 1`

Comment: Thought so, thats why used `Rally.data.BulkRecordUpdater.updateRecords` to update the Parent of features. But now suppose one MMF contains 5 features, it shows 6 features copied. strange

Comment: Seems like the original question you posted here was answered: the problem was that a full object was used instead of ref. You may want to accept this one so issues aren't mixed up. Your next comment raised a different issue, a closure in the loop. Did you fix it and now get a concurrency error?  I have an app example using a BulkRecordUpdater. It updates a Workproduct on a group of test cases, and the sintax similar to what you need since a _ref of a user story is used to set Workproduct on tc. See: https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/bulk-update-test-cases-workproduct/blob/master/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks nick for the reply, but in the given example `'model: 'TestCase'` is there thats why creating `Rally.data.WsapiDataStore`, but I have array of features so have to create `Rally.data.custom.Store`, its the reason  contains 5 features, it shows 6 features copied? I am not able to figure it out.