# Not able to update parent for all PortfolioItem/Feature which I copied for particular PortfolioItem/MMF

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, rally

I am trying to set parent for features which I copied for particular MMF, but parent is getting set for only last feature.

Below line of code to set the parent
Record is new feature object
_newParent is the MMF object, where I am doing wrong

`record.set("Parent", _newParent.get("_ref")),`

Need help please.Any suggestions?

Whole is method is this

```
           _genericInnerCopy: function(_childObj) {
                that = this;
                model = that.model;
                var record = Ext.create(model, {
                    Name: _childObj.get('Name'),
                    //Parent: _newParent.get("_ref");,
                });
                record.save({
                    callback: function(result, operation) {
                        if(operation.wasSuccessful()) {
                            console.log("Done");
                            //that._copyChild();
                        } else {
                            console.log("error");
                        }
                    }
                })
                that._all_pis.push(record);
                console.log("all pis values", that._all_pis);
                var store = Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
                    data: that._all_pis,
                    listeners: {
                        load: that._updateAll,
                        scope: that
                    },     
                });
                //console.log("record values", that._all_pis);
            },  
            _updateAll: function(store,data) {
                console.log("store values", store);
                console.log("data values", data);
                Rally.data.BulkRecordUpdater.updateRecords({
                    records: data,
                    propertiesToUpdate: {
                        Parent: _newParent.get("_ref")
                    },
                    success: function(readOnlyRecords){
                        //all updates finished, except for given read only records
                    },
                    scope: that
                });
                //that._createNewItems(that._all_pis);
            },
```

Comment: where is _newParent being set? Also, what is the output of your console.log statements?

Comment: @pherris -  Thanks for the reply. _newParent is being set when I am copying the MMF in the start, it is a global element. I updated the question with console log.

Comment: are those the correct console.logs? they don't contain the text "Parent prior to update" which is in your code example.

Comment: @pherris - its values are null, as those are newly copied features

Comment: after console.log("error"); can you add console.log(operation.getError()); or just console.log(operation); to find out what the error is?

Comment: @pherris - Wow I was not knowing this, operation shows errors. this is the error I am getting                      `Concurrency conflict: [Object has been modified since being read for update in this context] - ConcurrencyConflictException : Modified since read on update : Object Class : com.f4tech.slm.domain.PortfolioItem : ObjectID : 23365091021"length: 1`

Comment: @pherris - Thanks pherris, with the help of operation console I made changes and it works, now parent is got set for all features but if suppose there were 5 featues I copied, it shows 1 duplicate feature copied. something strange. See question for updated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your original question was that your code wasnt spitting out the errors in the callback. To see the errors you can console.log(operation.getError()) or console.log(operation) and inspect the output.

Comment: @sontya Please try to avoid changing the question - you can mark this one as complete and start a new question for your latest issues.

Comment: sorry, I wl remember this. and will put another question